# HashMap key with multiple values

Tags: java

I'm trying to bind some indexes and they're corresponding strings so I tried using a HashMap like so:

```
public class NewClass {
static List<String> referenceList = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String x = "AGE_X";
    String y = "AGE_Y";
    //String w = "AGE_Z";
    referenceList.add(x);
    referenceList.add(y);

    String text1 = "if ( AGE_X = = 10 ){\r\n"
            + " j = 1;"
            + " AGE_X = 5 ;"
            + " if ( true ) {"
            + " m = 4 / AGE_Y ;"
            + " }"
            + " }";
    detectEquals(text1);
}

public static String detectEquals(String text) {
    String a = null;
    // text = TestSplitting.addDelimiters(text);
    String[] newString = text.split(" ");
    List<String> test = Arrays.asList(newString);
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> signs = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        a = test.get(i).trim();
        //System.out.println("a=" + a);
        strBuilder.append(a);   
        index = strBuilder.length() - a.length();

        if (a.equals("if") || a.equals("=")) {         
            refList.add(index);
            // System.out.println(refList);
            signs.put(a, refList);
            refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            System.out.println(signs);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
}
```

But I am not having any luck with it. I'm trying to get every "if" and "=" from that string(text1) and map them together but it seems I am doing something wrong, because my output looks like this :

> {if=[0]}
>
> {if=[0], ==[8]}
>
> {if=[0], ==[9]}
>
> {if=[0], ==[15]}
>
> {if=[0], ==[23]}
>
> {if=[26], ==[23]}
>
> {if=[26], ==[36]}

I am looking for something like :

> if=[0,26] and = =[8,9,15,23,23,36]

I need some help with figuring out where I'm making a mistake here? Or am I just not printing them out properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 if (a.equals("if") || a.equals("=")) {         

            // System.out.println(refList);
            if(signs.containsKey(a)){
                signs.get(a).add(index);
            }
            else{
                refList.add(index);
                signs.put(a, refList);
            }
            refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            System.out.println(signs);
        }
```

Comment: thank you that did it. Thank you all for the help i'm glad i can ask even such simple questions and people take the time to answer.

Comment: @DanielV: While that does indeed fix the problem, I would still advise you to use Guava. Wouldn't you prefer your code to be simply: `signs.put(a, index);`? That's what Multimap would give you.

Comment: oh i would, but i was asked to not use any "outside tools" (why i do not know) at least for now.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) - I suggest you use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) and its implementations of the [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface so you don't have to reinvent the wheel :)

It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do, but your existing code always creates a new list *after* putting a reference to the old list in the map... I don't know why you're doing that. I'd expect something more like:

- Check whether `a` already exists as a key in the map

  - If so, fetch the value (the existing list) and add `index` to it
  - If not, create a new list, put that in the map, and add `index` to it

Comment: I don't think he wants a multi map, he wants a hashmap with a key and multiple values. The problem is he is not reusing the list and creating it again in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, i am currently looking at google MultiMap. But is there any way to do it without using these?.

Comment: @user989452: Yes, you *can* do it yourself, using code which is *similar* to what you've got... but it can get fiddly, compared with using an implementation which has already been written and tested...

Comment: hmm, well I was going by this post http://www.coderanch.com/t/385085/java/java/Implementing-HashMap-multiple-values-key in trying to figure out how to implement it. That is why i was creating a new list after putting a reference to the old list in the map, I think my mind got to jumbled up :)

Comment: @Jon: The title is misleading, but the user989452's intention was not to store multiple values as key but to store multiple values against a  key

Comment: @Manoj: Yes, I understood that - and that's exactly what `Multimap` does. From the docs: "A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values with a single key." Basically, each key is associated with a list of values - just as in the OP's code and your answer.

Comment: I apologize for the misleading title.

Comment: @user989452: I didn't find it misleading, as far as I'm aware. I believe Manoj is confused as to what Multimap does.

Comment: @Jon, I was thinking of multiKeyMap all the while, Now its all clear

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
public static String detectEquals(String text) {
            String a = null;
            // text = TestSplitting.addDelimiters(text);
            String[] newString = text.split(" ");
            List<String> test = Arrays.asList(newString);
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            HashMap<String, List<Integer>> signs = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
            List<Integer> refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
                a = test.get(i).trim();
                //System.out.println("a=" + a);
                strBuilder.append(a);
                index = strBuilder.length() - a.length();

                if (a.equals("if") || a.equals("=")) {
                    // System.out.println(refList);
                    refList = signs.get(a);
                    if(refList == null) {
                        refList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    }
                    refList.add(index);

                    signs.put(a, refList);

                }
            }
            System.out.println(signs);
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: Note that there's no need to call `signs.put` when you've just updated an existing list; you could put that in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String x = "AGE_X";
    String y = "AGE_Y";
    referenceList.add(x);
    referenceList.add(y);
    String text1 = "if ( AGE_X = = 10 ){\r\n" + " j = 1;" + " AGE_X = 5 ;" + " if ( true ) {" + " m = 4 / AGE_Y ;"
            + " }" + " }";
    detectEquals(text1);
}

public static String detectEquals(String text)
{
    String a = null;
    String[] newString = text.split(" ");
    List<Integer> tests = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> equals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < newString.length; i++)
    {
        a = newString[i].trim();
        //System.out.println("a=" + a);
        if(a.equals("if"))
        {
            tests.add(index);
        }
        else
        {
            if(a.equals("="))
            {
                equals.add(index);
            }
        }
        index += newString[i].length();
    }
    print("if", tests);
    print("=", equals);
    return a;
}

private static void print(String s, List l)
{
    System.out.print(s+"=[");
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    if(i.hasNext()) System.out.print(i.next());
    while(i.hasNext())
        System.out.print(","+i.next());
    System.out.println("]");
}
```